# access XMLHttpRequests send(data) in PHP backend

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-headers

I have an XMLHttpRequest sending data to a PHP backend.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url);

req.onload = function() {
  // This is called even on 404 etc
  // so check the status
  if (req.status == 200) {
    // Resolve the promise with the response text
    resolve(req.response);
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise reject with the status text
    // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
    reject(Error(req.statusText));
  }
};

// Handle network errors
req.onerror = function() {
  reject(Error("Network Error"));
};

// Make the request
req.send('query=messages'); // <-- i want to access this in php
```

i tried
`print_r($_GET)` and  `print_r($_REQUEST)` but neither works.

anyone knows how to access this data?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: yes @JayBlanchard it doesn't seem to deliver query=message at all:

GET /rest/api.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8000/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Comment: See my answer below why that is...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes thanks a lot! i answered the comment before i read your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only send data through the `XMLHttpRequest.send()`-method for POST-requests, not GET.

For GET-requests, you need to append the data to the url as query string.

```
url += "?query=message";
```

Then you can retrieve the data with PHP using:

```
$message = $_GET['query'];
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: aaah okay, i didn't know. using XMLHttpRequest to call a PHP REST API seems a bit unconvenient then since i have to use URL for GET and send() for POST. is there a better aproach to this in vanilla js?

Comment: Not really. I would make a small wrapper for it and use it like: `ajax.get(url, data, callback);` and `ajax.post(url, data, callback)` and handle the request in those methods.